# How to access gradients and modify weights (parameters) directly during training with CNTK?

Tags: python, deep-learning, cntk

I would like to calculate gradient value (per example or mini-batch), and modify weights directly to any value (so I can control the gradient descend with any method, not just the supplied sgd / learning rate schedule).
I am using the python interface.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to check out the [How to Ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on asking a question that's likely to get answers: in particular, seeing what you've already tried and why it doesn't work is important.

Answer (score 1):

To get the gradient see the `grad` method [in the docs](https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/graph.html#cntk.ops.functions.Function.grad). To update the weights for now you can use the `.value` property:

```
>>> w = C.Parameter((2,3), init=C.glorot_uniform())
>>> w.value
array([[-0.80213612, -0.7965923 , -0.10688281],
       [-1.0493834 , -0.32666588,  0.90124035]], dtype=float32)
>>> w.value = w.value + 1
>>> w.value
array([[ 0.19786388,  0.2034077 ,  0.89311719],
       [-0.0493834 ,  0.67333412,  1.90124035]], dtype=float32)
```

CNTK has on its roadmap support for easy specification of user defined learners which will reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to write. Expect this to be available around March 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_203_Reinforcement_Learning_Basics.ipynb) that does such operations:

> # Wait for some batches to finish to reduce noise if episode_number % BATCH_SIZE_BASELINE == 0:
>
> ```
> grads = {W1: gradBuffer['W1'].astype(np.float32),
>          W2: gradBuffer['W2'].astype(np.float32)}
> updated = sgd.update(grads, BATCH_SIZE_BASELINE)
>
> # reset the gradBuffer
> gradBuffer = dict((var.name, np.zeros(shape=var.shape))
>         for var in loss.parameters if var.name in ['W1', 'W2', 'b1', 'b2'])
> ```